# Installing whatsapp

Tags: wine

Is there any way to get a desktop-level client for WhatsApp.So you can use the call and video call functionality, as well as these, which were added to the latest version for windows. Wine is showing .net 4 errors.

Comment: Have you considered installing `whatsdesk` from the Ubuntu Software center? [Link here](https://snapcraft.io/whatsdesk)

Comment: Yup but it does not support calling functionality

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a port of WhatsApp for Linux. The best you can get is probably franz https://meetfranz.com/

Comment: Yeah but it does not support calling functionality

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo snap install whatsapp-for-linux
```

Comment: Note: `whatsapp-for-linux` is an **unofficial** WhatsApp desktop application for Linux.